# Deleting bulk users from aem using excel and curl

Tags: aem, aem-6

I there any way to delete multiple users from aem useradmin console.I have the list of users with there userid in excel sheet. Any way to import list of users from excel sheet and can I delete users using curl command?.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete users with curl:
curl -u : -FdeleteAuthorizable= http://localhost:4502/home/users/t/testuser

But to do so, you need to know the path to the user. Since users are nowadays stored in a node with a generic name (rather than with the user id as node name), you might need to search for them before they can be deleted.

If you have lots of users on AEM you might want to think about using ldap or something else for user management.

Comment: Hi @Oliver Gebert. Thanks for your comments. I am not much familiar about LDAP. Could you please provide me any references if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct utility available to do a bulk deletion of users.
CURL commands are easier to execute.

You can use the User Exporter utility in the ACS-Commons (https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/exporters/users/index.html) to download the list of users/groups in the system which will give you the paths of the users/groups.
Once you got the CSV downloaded, you can use the Paths to create CURL commands to delete the list of users.

You can also use applyTo parameter to delete them in a single request https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#deleting-multiple-items

But as there are more than 500, it is best to divide them into individual/fewer commands which will be easier for tracking